# Is there a built-in procedure for simultaneous diagonalization of a set of commuting matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set $\{A_1,...,A_m\}$ of $m$ commuting $N\times N$ diagonalizable matrices, it is known that there exists a basis of eigenvectors $\Lambda$ that simultaneously diagonalizes all the $A_i$.

Is there an automated way to compute $\Lambda$ in Mathematica?

For a pair of matrices $\{A_1,A_2\}$ it can be done "by hand" using `Eigenvectors` to first compute the eigenvectors $\Lambda_1$ of $A_1$, finding similarity transforms $P_k$ that act on the degenerate subspaces of $\Lambda_1$ to make them also eigenvector of $A_2$, and then combining the transformed degenerate subspaces together to form $\Lambda$, but I don't know how to generalize this to more than 2 matrices.

Comment: I'll mention the [related post at Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/243431?p_p_auth=zUhzpwN9)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks, I applied `Eigenvectors` to the matrix pencil $L(\lambda)=\sum_{j=1}^m\lambda^jA_j$ and it worked for $m=3$ matrices using a random real value for $\lambda$, providing a basis set which simultaneously diagonalized all three. How sensitive is it to floating point errors in the $A_j$ that spoil the commutativity slightly? It seems there is a fair amount of material available online on it, so I'll look into it further.

Comment: I don't know how sensitive it is. I suspect it is fine when the "near commuting" n x n matrices each have n distinct (and reasonably well separated) eigenvalues. At degeneracies it might not be so nice since eigenspaces can start to get pretty cranky.

Comment: I'll add that use of such matrices shows up in numerically solving polynomial systems via eigensystems. My take is that one should do as much as possible to avoid multiple eigendecompositions, so I've used random linear operators to avoid multiplicity whenever possible. This is, in effect, what you did via random lambdas. How well this generalizes to other applications I cannot say.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Interesting, my 3 test matrices each had several multiple-degenerate subspaces, but it still seemed to work fine without getting cranky.

Comment: (1) My guess could well be wrong. (2) It might be the case that the method works fine except when there are nontrivial blocks in the Jordan decomposition (that is, when the matrices do not have a full set of eigenvectors). So if your matrices are degenerate but not derogatory then maybe all works well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll make this a response since it seems to be a popular topic today (it showed up independently [on the Wolfram Community forum](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/243431?p_p_auth=M6gD94v8)).

One can usually do this by finding the eigenvectors for a random linear combination of the matrices. This works for nonderogatory matrices, that is, ones that do not have nontrivial blocks in their Jordan decomposition. In different terms, it works when all eigenvalues have algebraic multiplicity equal to geometric multiplicity.

Comment: That's probably why it worked in my case: all the matrices $A_k$ I had were all either unitary or symmetric, and thus admitted eigendecompositions. Thanks!

Comment: Minor update: Actually, the matrices I used were symmetric. I tried it on unitary matrices (not necessarily symmetric) with root-of-unity eigenvalues and it failed. So some caution and double-checking may be necessary (by verifying that $\Lambda^{-1}\mathbf{A}_k\Lambda$ is in fact diagonal for all $k$).

Comment: When it failed, were the matrices in question all verified to commute? Because I would expect this method to behave if so.

Comment: I'll post the explicit matrices to my question later today, just so that other people can play around with it to see an explicit example (or point out that I'm making a mistake).

Comment: Never mind, I made a mistake while verifying the diagonalization, it works fine.

Comment: Is there any reference to a proof of the above statement? I would be very interested.

Comment: @Gert Which "above statement"?

Comment: @Daniel That for nonderogatory matrices the system of common eigenvectors can be found by diagonalising (almost) any random linear combination of the matrices

Comment: Might be here though I am not sure. https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/258726.258767?download=true

Comment: Also related: http://pcmap.unizar.es/~jaca2018/PDFXIV/sauer.pdf (see in particular Problem 1 therein)

Comment: And I still do not have a good reference. But here is one (unfortunately behind a paywall) that shows why I might care about the property and how it can be used: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-96418-8_40

Comment: And here is something relevant: http://www.jssac.org/Editor/Suushiki/V07/No4/V7N4_102.pdf (see theorem 18)

Comment: Diagonalizable matrices are non-derogatory.

Comment: @MaxM An identity matrix for dimension larger than one would be a counterexample to your statement. Nondiagonalizable matrices are deficient. Different concept.

Comment: You are right. But for the identity matrix algebraic multiplicity of eigenvalue 1 in characteristic polynomial is n, and geometric also n. Is this not what you mean by "all eigenvalues have algebraic multiplicity equal to geometric multiplicity"? I suppose you mean in the minimal polynomial, but this was not clear to me (and also is not what googling gives for "algebraic and geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue").

Comment: BTW, irrespective of my terminological confusion, the result in question works for all sets of simultaneously diagonalizable matrices, derogatory or not.